# Draw Triangle With Curved Side And Straight Sides Using UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

**Background**

I have some simple code that draws a triangle with three straight sides using UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer. The result is in image A, below.

However, I want the longest side of the triangle to have an inwards curve. The desired result is in image B, below.

---

**Question**

What change to the code below can achieve the longest side of the triangle to have an inwards curve? How do I instruct the path to curve?

---

**Code**

```
func drawShape() {
    
    let path1 = UIBezierPath()
    path1.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 600))
    path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 600))
    path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 50))
    path1.close()
    
    let shape1 = CAShapeLayer()
    shape1.path = path1.cgPath
    shape1.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1).cgColor
    
    view.layer.insertSublayer(shape1, at: 1)

}
```

---

**Image**

[image]

Comment: The easiest way is to replace the `addLine(to:)` for the longest side with a `addCurve(to:controlPoint:)` (i.e., a quadratic Bézier), where the “to” point is unchanged, but the “control point” is some point inside the triangle. What point you choose inside the triangle for that control point will dictate the shape of the Bézier. I would err towards a symmetric curve by choosing a control point equidistant between the two end points, but your curve doesn't look like it's symmetric.

Comment: Thank you Rob. I've got the code `path1.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 600), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: (300-50), y: (600*0.5)))` which seems to be working in a way that is expected. Will experiment further.

Answer (score 1):

I have added `addQuadCurve` before closing the path. It gives the desired result.

**Code**

```
func drawShape() {
    
    let path1 = UIBezierPath()
    path1.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 600))
    path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 600))
    path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 50))
    path1.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 600), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: (300-50), y: (600*0.5)))
    path1.close()
    
    let shape1 = CAShapeLayer()
    shape1.path = path1.cgPath
    shape1.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1).cgColor
    
    view.layer.insertSublayer(shape1, at: 1)

}
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Can you add an image of your results to your answer?

Comment: Sure can. Image added. Almost the same as the mocked up version.

Comment: Looks like you nailed it. (Voted)